# How to programmatically hide both field and label of Zend_Element_Checkbox?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am trying to set display:none attribute to Zend_Element_Checkbox. I have managed to hide checkbox itself. Unfortunately label keeps on displaying still.

Here is my code:

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'junior_accounts', array(
    'label' => 'Junior (15yrs & under)',
    'multiOptions' => $personNumberList,
    'tabindex' => $tabIndex++,
  ));

$this->getElement('junior_accounts')->setAttribs(array('style' => 'display: none'));
```

Is there any programmatical method of doing this or I need to set class of the element and add appropriate CSS definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to the label of the `Zend_Form_Element` via `Zend_Form_Element::getDecorator()`.  Then you can set the `style` option of the decorator to control its CSS properties.

```
$label = $this->getElement('junior_accounts')->getDecorator('Label');

if ($label instanceof Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract) {
    $label->setOption('style', 'display: none');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm - I just had to change $form to $this :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is hidden and it SHOULD STAY hidden all through the request, than you should rather change the element type from Select to Hidden. If you need to show it later (using JS), than you should also hide it using JS, making it accessible for users without JS. You can hide the element (assuming use of jQuery and a tag wrapping each element):

```
$('#elementId').parent().hide(); 
//or 
$('#elementId').parent().children().hide() // if you want the container visible
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work.

```
$this->getElement('junior_accounts')->removeDecorator('Label');
```

Haven't tested it so might have typo inside

Or if you just want to hide it:

```
$this->getElement('junior_accounts')->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('style', 'display: none');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be removing the element will be an option. If so, I did it this way:

```
$form->get('product')->remove('version');
```

Before validating the form:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('product')->get('version')->setRequired(FALSE);
```